# Connect to mysql database using an existing connection

Tags: mysql

Eveytime I connect   to a mysql database from my machine, it creates a new connection the database. For example, if I connect using `mysql -u<user> -p<password> -h<host> -P<port>` twice from my terminal, there will be 2 connections made from my machine to the database. Is there any way I can identify and connect via any existing connection from my machine to the database?

Comment: Mysql is designed to handle multiple connections. It's actually useful to identify which terminal is doing what. Is there any reason why you want to share the connections?

Comment: I want to share connections to reduce the time taken for connection creation/teardown. Also, my application is going to connect to the database very often thorough multiple clients and so the number of connections will spike up which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

As @lbu said MySQL is designed for multiple connections and if you closed your shell/connection, MySQL will close connection after timeout. Managing connections to MySQL is quite broad thing and to name a few things you can do about that:

1. Watching all connections to server

SHOW processlist

2. You can manage connections per user as in manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-resources.html
   like

CREATE USER 'francis'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'frank'
           WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 20
           MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 10
           MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 5
           MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 2;

3. You can manage connections globally on the server by following variables:
   max_connections and max_user_connections
4. You can manage connections via server-side language by constructing for example a singleton PHP class for connection to DB.